# How can I dasable "People" link for anonymous user on the jenkins main page?

Tags: jenkins, configuration

I am new to Jenkins and my task is to allow (restricted) anonymous access but to prevent the anonymous users from seeing Jenkins users list with their names and ids. I have tried all authorization strategies in the "Global Security" option, but didn't find any solution. Is there any way to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is currently not possible and an issue logged on this is still open https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18884. Just to add, the **People** link does not display Jenkins users but contributors to SCM repositories that have been built by Jenkins. See https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204498804-How-People-is-managed-by-Jenkins-.

Comment: @Dibakar Aditya Thank you for the reply and additional information. :-) It is a pity, that it is currently not possible.